# How to parse a data from the serial input stream data?

Tags: java, serial-port

Actually, I have created a JFrame which detect a serial com ports and after selection of the com ports, I'm getting a input stream data from my (Arduino) and i'm receiving that data into an byte array using the "SerialDataListener" method "event.getReceivedData()" and now i'm trying to parse a data in integer/string form from that byte array...

Arduino's input is --> ##00000000Gas Flow OTP Wet Air          000.00LPM 010.21008.7  which is continuously coming to the serial port after 2 seconds delay..

I'm getting the same output but one character after one like :

##0
##00 and so on....

I've created a Jframe using Drag & Drop facility of Apache Netbeans IDE and added some actions to get com port and here,
This is my code to read the data of serial com port and adding that data in my jTextArea... I'm getting the same output what Arduino is sending but I'm looking for only some part of that data example

input:- ##00000000Gas Flow OTP Wet Air          000.00LPM 010.21008.7
output(jTextArea):- Same as input

Expectation :- 000.00LPM (Only this part should print on jTextArea) or Is there any way to store that part/data from the input stream data.. Thank You..

```
private void Serial_EventBasedReading(SerialPort activePort){
    activePort.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener(){
        public int getListeningEvents(){return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;}
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
            byte[] newData = event.getReceivedData();
            for(int i=0;i<newData.length;i++){
                dataBuffer = dataBuffer + (char)newData[i]; 
                jTextArea_lgfc1.setText(dataBuffer); 
                System.out.println(dataBuffer); // This line is just to check how data is printing
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra sorry sir, But pls focus on problem. I've named all the variable based on my conditions..

Comment: well, you are requesting help and that help should also be useful to future readers (as of the mission of this site) - so it's your job to make the question as clear as possible to all readers _here_: conventions help in that goal (what you do in your private context is a different matter). Please learn java naming conventions (the java tag wiki has a summery and references) and apply them when showing your code publicly. BTW: be careful with gender assumptions .. (yours is wrong ;)

Comment: @kleopatra actually i'm new to this platform ma'am.. Can you please point some of mistakes so that I can take some reference..

Comment: `String s = new String(event.getReceivedData());jTextArea_lgfc1.setText(s.replaceAll(".*?([\\d.]+LPM).*", "$1"));` Your loop is redundant and very inefficient. If you want a continuous readout you might consider `jTextArea_lgfc1.append`

Comment: *If you want a continuous readout you might consider...* (i.e. don't keep a redundant copy of the text area's text in `dataBuffer` [unnecessary])

Comment: @g00se can you please give a comprehensive code/explanation Because I tried this one out but this didn't worked. I'm getting nothing except one character one by one in my Text Area

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I might delete my last comment, the reason being, I realise I'm not 100% sure what's happening in that callback. In the meantime, please replace *all* the code inside `serialEvent` with `System.out.println(new String(event.getReceivedData()));` and post a sample of the output *formatted as code* ***in your question***

Comment: @g00se brother, i tried this one out and it is working fine (printing the input to the console ) but my problem is I've to show that data in my jTextArea and not the complete string/stream of data , I've to parse the desired from that stream.. example my input is: "##0000000Gas Flow OTP Dry Air      XXX.XXLPM 032.42152.5" (This ia a dummy reading of a Gas sensor) and now  I just need that "XXX.XXLPM" part and remember one thing this reading is changing each 2 seconds of delay and printing its reading in new line. I've to parse that desired data for each reading and print it to my jTextArea. :)

Comment: Please follow the instructions I gave you. That last code was *not* meant to be a solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the code. In the second `SerialPortDataListener`, the `while` loop is calling `inputStream.read()` instead of `inputStream2.read()`. Here is the corrected code:

```
/*code*/
//Global Variables
SerialPort sp1, sp2;
String dataBuffer="";
InputStream inputStream1,inputStream2;


private void Serial_EventBasedReading(SerialPort sp1, SerialPort sp2){
    sp1.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener(){
        public int getListeningEvents(){return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;}
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){

            inputStream1 = sp1.getInputStream();
            try {
                while(inputStream1.read() > 0){                  
                    System.out.println(convertIStoString(inputStream1));
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    sp2.addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener(){
        public int getListeningEvents(){return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_RECEIVED;}
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){

            inputStream2 = sp2.getInputStream();

            try {
                while(inputStream2.read() > 0){               
                    System.out.println(convertIStoString(inputStream2));
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

//This is a helper method which will read a complete line and returns the desired/parsed part in string..

private String convertIStoString(InputStream inputStream){

    try{
        String result="";
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\n");
        result = sc.next();
        dataBuffer = result.substring(35,41);
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "WAIT!");
    }
    return dataBuffer;
}
```

Other than the typo fix, the code looks fine. The `convertIStoString` method reads a complete line from the input stream and extracts the desired part (the substring from index 35 to 41) and returns it as a string. The returned string is then printed to the console, and later can be converted to a float for arithmetic calculations.